# Lowering resistance of potentiometer?

Tags: resistors, potentiometer

I saw a video where a person wired a resistor to the outer pins of a potentiometer to lower the resistance. Does this work? And if it does, can I still use the wiper and an outer pin with it lowered? Here is the video for reference https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W-TmOLPDLhc&t=66s.

Comment: Yes it works. Look up parallel resistances and note whether the larger or smaller  one dominates as the values get very different. Not that linearity is NOT maintained.

Comment: @DKNguyen Oh, hello. Why didn't you answer this question in the other post?

Comment: @DKNguyen So if I use one of those calculators, would they be accurate? I tried one with the original pot being 500 ohms, and the resistor being 3 ohms, and it said something around 3 ohms. So if I wire a 3 ohm resistor to the outer pins of a 500 ohm pot, would it actually be around 3 ohms max if I use the wiper and one other pin?

Comment: @EmeraldVolts, What do you still want to do with this 3-pin variable resistor? Do you need it as a rheostat or potentiometer? If it will be a rheostat (2-pin variable resistor), then connect the resistor between the wiper and some of the outer pins.

Comment: @Circuitfantasist By some of the outer pins, do you mean one of them?

Comment: @EmeraldVolts, Yes, I do.

Comment: @Circuitfantasist Ok, thank you! Should work fine for my project! And how does this work? Does some current go through the resistor to give some more current?

Comment: @EmeraldVolts Yes, you just have two resistors (the one variable and the other constant) in parallel. There are many resources about the parallel resistor connection in the web. Here is a resistance calculator - http://www.sengpielaudio.com/calculator-paralresist.htm where you can find your case.

Comment: @Circuitfantasist Ok, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

> I saw a video where a person wired a resistor to the outer pins of a potentiometer to lower the resistance. Does this work?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fe2Cuq.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. (a) R1 has no effect on the potentiometer. (b) R5 does have an effect on the potentiometer.*

- In Figure 1a the potentiometer is driven by the preceding amplifier which will use negative feedback (not shown) to drive the output to the desired level. Adding R2 makes no difference in this case other than to waste power.
- In Figure 1b R4 and R3 form their own potential divider which limits the voltage when R3 is at the "max" position. The max value will depend on the ratio of R4 to R3. By adding R5 in parallel with the potentiometer we cause a greater voltage drop across R4 and this again decreases the maximum output of the potentiometer.

The overall effect will also depend on what impedance is connected to OUT.

You can model this in a spreadsheet using the series and parallel resistance formulas. Alternatively set it up in a simulator such as CircuitLab (available on the editor toolbar on this site) and do a sweep simulation. In Figure 2 I've run a DC sweep on R2.K (the wiper position) and obtained the result of Figure 3.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fCgy9H.png)</sup>

*Figure 2. Circuit for simulation.*

[image]

*Figure 3. Results of simulation.*

Note the non-linearity as a result of the relatively high load of R4.

Comment: Sorry, I'm kinda a beginner, could you simplify that for me please?

Comment: I'll do that if you'll edit your question to explain what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I just want to lower the resistance of a pot, since the low resistance ones are more expensive.

Comment: Why? What value? For what application? Where in the circuit? Usually pots are available in a wide range of values for a particular style and all are the same price. Again, put all the information in your question where everyone will see it.

Comment: The other person on this post already told me what I needed. I needed something around 3 ohms, and the lowest I found was 10 ohms, cheapest being $2.25

Comment: I'm struggling with something else though. I'm trying to solder some wires to the pins of a light strip, but the problem is that the solder isn't sticking, it keeps coming off. Sometimes I can kinda get it to stick, but it always comes of.

Comment: If you're not going to answer the questions then I can't help you any more. Read my previous comment.

Comment: All I need now is just how to solder wires to lightstrip pins. I think they are copper? I'm not sure.

Comment: OK. You still haven't provided the information I requested. I suspect that you haven't understood the resistor problem yet and may burn it out in incorrect configuration.